# Can an Oracle 19c database dblink to an Oracle 10.2.3 database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, dblink, oracle-19c

I have an Oracle 12.1.0.2 database that dblinks to an Oracle 10.2.0.3.0 database.
I am upgrading the Oracle 12.1.0.2 database to 19c (12.2.0.3).

Will my dblinks to the Oracle 10.2.0.3.0 database continue to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this document from Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/207303_1.html), the answer appears to be "No". A 19c client (the owner of your DB Link) is only supported/compatible with a server version of 11.2 or greater.

Conversely, a 10.2 database can only support a client as new as 12.1, so any upgrade of your 12.1 database to any newer version will break your db link.

Comment: 19c to 10.2.0.3 is not a supported combination but it does work for me in my configuration.

Comment: Thanks,  while it's not an Oracle supported config, you've also demonstrated that it technically does work..

Comment: Just because something works doesn't mean that Oracle _guarantees_ that it will continue to work, or that it is secure. No production infrastructure should be built on anything that isn't certified and supported. Anything else is just operating on borrowed time.

Comment: If it were up to me I would upgrade and patch everything to the latest and greatest but that is not the financial reality of my situation. Probably many other companies are in the same boat.

Comment: @pmdba -  "Just because something works doesn't mean that Oracle guarantees that it will continue to work,".  Reminds me of my early years as a COBOL programmer. IBM introduced COBOL-85, with significant enhancements.  We raised the question with our local rep if our existing compiled libraries would continue to work.  The response was "if you do not recompile, they will continue to work . . .  until such time as they don't"     Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I am upgrading from 11.2 to 19 and my link to 10.2.0.3 works:

```
SQL> select * from v$version@MYDBLINK;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bi

SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

I have a link to a 9.2 database and it does not work, but I have a work around.

Bobby

Answer (score -1):

@Bobby Durrett,

Could you please share the work-around you used that worked to establish dblink between 9i or 10g DB with 19c

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/182265)